# Is it possible to target a VSTO add-in to .NET 4.6.1 (VS2012)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, vsto, .net-4.6.1

When I installed .NET 4.6.1 and the Targeting Pack, then tried to target my (document) VSTO add-in (from 4.5) to 4.6.1, I get this:

"Attempted re-targeting of the project has been canceled. The .NET Framework version you selected is not supported by this project type."

Related to [Can I create a VSTO outlook addin targeting .net framework 4.6.1, which runs on all office versions from 2007 to 2016?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425963/can-i-create-a-vsto-outlook-addin-targeting-net-framework-4-6-1-which-runs-on)

Seems like it should work. Do I need to start over or something?

Thanks,
- Rand

Comment: It is just a "you are voiding the warranty" message.  The VSTO version you have was tested to work for 4.5, they did not have a time machine back in 2012 to test it on 4.6.1.  Don't fight it, there is no point.  It will work just fine on a machine that has 4.6.1 installed.

Comment: Steve, it's more than a warning message. VSTO Projects will not convert to a target of .net 4.6.1 on VS2012. Neither can new Addin projects be started with 4.6.1, only 4.5.  I got an answer on another board that Visual Studio 2015 will support vsto on 4.6.1, but I have not seen the documentation for that.